# Solving a problem with comparing numbers in DEBUG.EXE and outputting the largest number

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16, dosbox

There was a problem with understanding and how to solve the problem with DEBUG.EXE.

Assignment:

> In the DEBUG debugger, write a program that allows you to enter single-digit numbers from the keyboard, compare them and output the largest of them. Save the program to disk.

Studying the documentation and commands that could be used to solve the problem and write the program code, it was not possible to come up with even working code. One of the previous attempts to launch the program in DEBUG.EXE via DOSBox ended in a crash.
How should the code be written so that the program will work, and even be capable of the above operations in the task when it is launched?

I used the following code as one of the attempts:

```
n prog.com
a 100
mov ah, 01
int 21
mov al, dl
mov ah, 01
int 21
mov bl, dl
cmp al, bl
jae 116
mov dl, al
int 21
jmp 11a
mov dl, bl
int 21
ret
```

Comment: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm `int 21h` / `ah=1` returns in AL, not DL.  (Another good reference: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html although it seems to be down at the moment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new file under control of the Operating System which DEBUG can write data to

   `-n d:\prog.com`
2. Machine executable code in memory starts at CS:0100

   `-a 100`

```
Offset  Opcodes     Instruction     Description

0100    b4 01       mov ah,1        ; 1st digit, character input with echo      
0102    cd 21       int 21h

0104    88 c2       mov dl,al       ; save result in dl

0106    b4 01       mov ah,1        ; 2nd digit, character input with echo
0108    cd 21       int 21h

010a    88 c6       mov dh,al       ; save result in dh

010c    38 f2       cmp dl,dh       ; compare digits
010e    77 0a       ja 0116         ; if greater
0110    72 04       jb 0114         ; if smaller    

0112    b6 3d       mov dh,3dh      ; digits are equal, print '='
                    
0114    88 f2       mov dl,dh        

0116    b4 02       mov ah,2        ; print out digit
0118    cd 21       int 21h

011a    b8 00 4c    mov ax,4c00h    ; quit to dos
011d    cd 21       int 21h
```

4. Save to file 1fh (31) bytes

```
-rcx
CX 0000
:1f
```

5. Save & quit

```
-w
Writing 0001f bytes
-q
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I don't get it why you preferred to write `mov cl, 8` `shr dx, cl` over the much simpler `mov dl, dh` ?  And if you replace the above `mov dl,3dh` by `mov DH, 3Dh`, you can even shave off the jump! A total saving of 4 bytes (more than 10%).

Comment: @SepRoland First I tried `shr dx,8` but it doesn't work in debug.exe. Intel manual says it is valid instruction. 
`C1 /5 ib | SHR r/m16,  imm8 | C1 EA imm8`. So I used `mov cl, 8 | shr dx, cl`.
I didn't take into account code size. Well, here is lesson for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Nassau MS-DOS original Debug only understands 8086 instructions, `shr reg16, imm8` is an 186+ instruction. You can use it in FreeDOS Debug/X, Enhanced Debug, or [lDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug) however.

Comment: @ecm Yeah, mS-DeBug is archaic tool. Indeed this instruction was available from 80186/188. `"On the 8086,88 ... The count
may be specified as the constant 1 or as register CL
allowing the shift count to be a variable supplied at
execution time.In addition the 80186,188 allow the
number of shifts to be specified as an immediate
value in the instruction. This eliminates the need for
a MOV immediate to the CL register if the number
of shifts required is known at assembly time"` http://www.bitsavers.org/components/intel/80186/210911-001_iAPX86_88_186_188_Programmers_Reference_1983.pdf